# Save lines from textarea to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My goal is to extract each line from a textarea and save it to my mysql db.

I think my problem lies within the AJAX function or the part, where I get the lines from the textarea, but see yourself:

```
//#userip = textarea;


    var content = $("#user_ip").val();
    var ips = content.split("\n");

    $.ajax({
        type:       'POST',
        url:        'inc.php?ban_user',
        data:       'user_ip='+ips,
        dataType:   'html',
        success:    function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

And the PHP part is:

```
        if (isset($_POST["user_ip"])) {

        $user_ip   = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["user_ip"]));

            mysql_query("INSERT into banned (ip) values ('$user_ip')") or die(mysql_error());

        echo($user_ip);

    }
```

At this point `$user_ip` seems to be just one string of all textarealines combined.

I know that this way the php code above wont work and it will save all lines as one result!

What I want: Save each txtarea-line seperatly in my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"data" attribute want an object with "attribute":value pairs, and your give him a string.

```
$.ajax({
        type:       'POST',
        url:        'inc.php?ban_user',
        data:       {'user_ip': ips},
        dataType:   'html',
        success:    function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't split the user entered string on client side (ajax) but within the php script.

```
if (isset($_POST["user_ip"])) {
  $user_ip   = explode("\n",htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["user_ip"])));
  foreach ( $user_ip AS $uip ) {
    mysql_query("INSERT into banned (ip) values ('$uip')") or die(mysql_error());
    echo($uip);
  }
}
```

Comment: This might not work directly, you probably have to replace the line breaks with some special character within the ajax script.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with the following method call:

```
$lines = preg_split( '/\r\n|\r|\n/', $string );
```

This will give you an array of all lines in the text. After this you only need to iterate thru it and add every value to the database.

Comment: $lines = explode( PHP_EOL, $string );

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies within this:

```
var ips = content.split("\n");
```

`split()` returns an array of all the strings.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful if you'd showed us what $_POST["user_ip"] contained.

The $.val() method returns the value from the *first* element in a set - so it won't work with multiple textareas (if that's what you think it does).

You get the string value and convert it to a line-by line array of strings, then are doing an implicit conversion back to a single string - why? Just send the 'content' value to your script then split by newline there.

(and BTW, the code will still be vulnerable to SQL injection).